# how to use sql count() function in java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I want to get a SQL Count of the number of records that pertain to my name column and display it into my JTextfield(variable name 'workers') . My code is written below. I'm getting an exception saying wrong column name. Any suggestion??

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        pst = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select count(name) from employee_details";
        rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next()){
          String ss = rs.getString("count(name)");
          workers.setText(ss);
      }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `rs.getInt(1)`.  Then you don't have to worry about what name the database assigns to the column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using column `name` use column `index`.

```
 String ss = rs.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an alias

```
String sql = "select count(name) as 'mycount' from employee_details";
    rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
  while(rs.next()){
      String ss = rs.getString("mycount");
      workers.setText(ss);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the count is an integer value do

```
    int ss = rs.getInt(1);
```

The `1` is the column number in the query. It starts at `1` and not `0`.

Another way is to name your column in the query

```
String sql = "select count(name) as 'cn' from employee_details";
```

And get the value by *column name*

```
int ss = rs.getInt("cn");
```